# Guardar dados dentro de um vetor com loop em Python

Tags: python, loop, lista

Boa tarde galera.
Eu venho aprendendo muito C e C++, e a parte também python. Me confunde muito as sintaxes as vezes, porque muitas vezes penso em C e me confundo em python. No caso do loop do python, eu gostaria de armazenar dados dentro de um vetor, e printar os dados, mas está dando alguns erros. Me ajudem ae :c

```
estudantes = []
i=0
while i < 4:
    estudantes[i] = input("Digite o nome do aluno: ")   
    i+=1

while i<len(estudantes):
    print("Aluno {}: {}".format(i, estudantes[i]))
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Utilize [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), em conjunto com o laço de repetição `for`, para criar uma sequência dentro do intervalo `[0,4]` e alimentar sua lista.
- Adicione um item ao final da lista chamando o método [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).
- Use o laço de repetição `for` para iterar ao longo da lista.
- Recupere o índice do item dentro da lista chamando o método [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
estudantes = []
for i in range(4):
  estudantes.append(input("Digite o nome do aluno: "))

for x in estudantes:
  print("Aluno {}: {}".format(estudantes.index(x), x))
```

Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/JKAY/0).

Comment: Brigadão mercador :D

Comment: @Alex se resolveu o seu problema, considere marcar a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

- Utilize "insert" para inserir elementos na lista através de seu índice (em python não é valido por atribuição).
- Como vc começou um novo loop "while" é necessário também redefinir a contagem da variável de controle (i=0).

Resultado final:

```
estudantes = []
i=0
while i < 4:
     estudantes.insert(i, input("Digite o nome do aluno: "))  
     i+=1
i=0    
while i < len(estudantes):
     print("Aluno {}: {}".format(i, estudantes[i]))
     i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Para você armazenar os valores dentro de um vetor, você pode utilizar o `while` ou o `for`.

Abaixo, exibo uma forma de resolver esta questão utilizando o laço de repetição `for`:

```
# Capturando e tratando a quantidade de estudantes:
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Desejas inserir quantos nomes de estudantes? '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

# Capturando e inserindo o nome de cada estudante na lista "estudantes":
estudantes = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    estudantes.append(input(f'Digite o nome do {c}º estudante: '))

# Exibindo a lista "estudantes":
print(f'\033[32mOs estudantes são: {estudantes}\033[m')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/uewjqchb-solkarped).

Observe que neste código foi implementado uma estrutura de tratamento de erros e exceções. Este bloco é necessário para restringir os erros mais comuns na hora da digitação. Neste caso em específico, o número de estudantes é restringido a apenas valores `inteiros` e `maiores` que `"0"`.